# Javascript : Table columns build dynamically with JSON datas. Row structure broken

Tags: javascript, ajax, html-table, innerhtml

I retrieve on my page 2 sets of data (json): 1: warehouses 2: items.
With the first I wan't to create dynamically the TD's of my table after getting an Ajax search response from my view.

I want to create all TD for all warehouses available in the warehouses JSON and if a product has a stock on this warehouse PK, in the same time, I populate the QTY

```
                tableBody.innerHTML += `
                    [...]
                     
                    <td>${item.fournisseur__nom}</td>`;
                JSON.parse(warehouses).forEach((wh) => {
                        tableBody.innerHTML += `
                        <td>
                        `;
                        for (let i = 0; i < item.sststock.length; i++) {
                            if (item.sststock[i].sst_id == wh.pk) {
                                tableBody.innerHTML += item.sststock[i].qty;
                            }
                        };
                        tableBody.innerHTML += `
                        </td>
                        `;
                    });

                tableBody.innerHTML += `   
                    <td>${item.qty}</td>

                    [...]
```

Alas, here the result :
[image]

I noticed that even if I remove the loop "for i", a `<tr></tr>` is inserted between the 2 `<td>` and when I put the loop back, between each `<td>`, a `<tr>` raises.
Any idea about the reason of this behaviour ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite multiple previous searches, I hadn't heard yet about **insertRow()** and **insertCell()** in JS.

Even if I still don't understand why `innerHTML <td>` didn't work, I changed my code with these 2 functions and result is OK.

```
const tableBody = document.querySelector('.table-body');
var newRow = tableBody.insertRow(-1);  // -1 = at the end of the table
var newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);  // 0 = at the 0 index
newCell.innerHTML = item.etat;
[...]
JSON.parse(warehouses).forEach((wh) => {
         var newCell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
         for (let i = 0; i < item.sststock.length; i++) {
             if (item.sststock[i].warehouse_id == wh.pk) {
                 newCell.innerHTML = item.sststock[i].qty;
             }
         };
    });
```